# Installing the brother dcp195c scanner on linux mint 18

Tags: linux-mint, scanner

I have a distribution of Linux Mint 18 and I wanted to install the Brother dcp195c printer definition scanner I used this method in link

https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=590793

And I encounter this error message:

```
(Gedit: 5809): Gtk-WARNING **: Calling Inhibit failed: GDBus.Error: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.gnome.SessionManager was not provided by any .service files

** (gedit: 5809): WARNING **: Set document metadata failed: Setting attribute metadata :: gedit-spell-enabled not supported

** (gedit: 5809): WARNING **: Set document metadata failed: Setting attribute metadata :: gedit-encoding not supported

** (gedit: 5809): WARNING **: Set document metadata failed: Setting attribute metadata :: gedit-position not supported
```

Is there a solution thank you.

Comment: it looks like they have a driver on their website: http://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadtop.aspx?c=eu_ot&lang=en&prod=dcp195c_all

Comment: i installed full driver of brother dcp195c but but i have the same problem